# Nice searchable select-box in jQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm just starting to use the jQuery framework.
I really like the look of SelectMenu plugin. But unfortunately I have quite large set of data, so going through them in selectbox is not possible.
So, I need to do some search in the dataset.

Does anybody know, whether there is any plugin that combines look of SelectMenu and features of Autocomplete in jQuery? Or is there any *easy* possibility to modify Autocomplete look (i.e. show multi-line records and format each line separately)?

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've done with the jquery-ui autocomplete module it is very easy to modify the look and feel of it. Just take a look at the methods and attributes on the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). If you don't necessarily like how the jquery-ui autocomplete works/is set up you could also look at this tutorial for simple list filter that you can also configure to what you want here: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I found [Select2 Plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to be very helpful for this kind of thing.